# ActionBar is not accessible in eclipse

Tags: android, android-actionbar

The below code is copied from following link..

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

I am not able to access ActionBar interface , eclipse always showing error on ActionBar

I have imported  android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;

But still I am facing the error ,

Can Any one please help me regarding the issue?

```
  public static class TabListener<T extends Fragment> implements ActionBar.TabListener {
        private Fragment mFragment;
        private final Activity mActivity;
        private final String mTag;
        private final Class<T> mClass;

        /** Constructor used each time a new tab is created.
          * @param activity  The host Activity, used to instantiate the fragment
          * @param tag  The identifier tag for the fragment
          * @param clz  The fragment's Class, used to instantiate the fragment
          */
        public TabListener(Activity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz) {
            mActivity = activity;
            mTag = tag;
            mClass = clz;
        }

        /* The following are each of the ActionBar.TabListener callbacks */

        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // Check if the fragment is already initialized
            if (mFragment == null) {
                // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity
                mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());
                ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
            } else {
                // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it
                ft.attach(mFragment);
            }
        }

        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            if (mFragment != null) {
                // Detach the fragment, because another one is being attached
                ft.detach(mFragment);
            }
        }

        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // User selected the already selected tab. Usually do nothing.
        }
    }
```

Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.fortestingonly"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.fortestingonly.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.fortestingonly.SecondActivity"></activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note : Keep `android:minSdkVersion="7"` and `android:targetSdkVersion="19"` in manifest file of your project. If 19 is not available then keep it greater than 16.

minimum sdk version is required to be 7 to use android-support-v7-appcompat library project.

Do following steps sequentially..Ignore steps which you have already done..

- Update your SDK (Latest version is 22.6.2)
- Update Android Support Library (Latest version is 19.1)
- Restart SDK
- In Eclipse Go to File >> Import >> Existing Code Into Workspace >> NEXT >> Browse >> (goto your sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat) >> OK >> FINISH
- You will see android-support-v7-appcompat project folder in Eclipse
- Goto android-support-v7-appcompat/libs
- Right Click on one of the jar file >> Build Path >> Add to Build Path (Repeat this for all remaining jar files)
- Right click on android-support-v7-appcompat project folder >> Build Path >> Configure Build Path >> Java Build Path (see list in left panel) >> Order And Export Tab (See right panel) >> Un-check Android Dependancies >> OK
- Go to your project >> Right Click >> Properties >> Android(see left panel) >> Add (see right panel on window) >> select android-support-v7-appcompat option from list >> OK >> Apply >> Finish
- Keep theme attribute in application tag of manifest as `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"`

If this doesn't work, clean your project as well as android-support-v7-appcompat project.

This should work..